# WordPress function on `publish_post` running twice (increments value by 2 instead of 1)

Tags: php, wordpress, increment

I am making a counter where I can count amount of posts ever posted on my blog and save the value in a option.

I have created a function that gets executed every time I publish new post, but the issue I see is that the counter value increases by 2 even though I only publish 1 post which I only want it to increase by one.

Here is the function gets executed every time I publish a post

Here is the function gets executed every time I publish a post

```
function post_type_counter0() {
$number0 = get_option( 'wp_count_po0' );
$number0++;

update_option( 'wp_count_po0', $number0 );
}
```

And the function is hooked to the action

```
add_action( 'publish_post', 'post_type_counter0' );
```

I also tried to specify the value to be added to $number0 variable by doing this way

```
$number + 1;
```

But it still increased the value by 2 instead of 1.

Any idea??

Comment: I've provided an answer, but I'm curious as to why you will be deleting posts instead of just making them a draft/pending/private? Generally non-destructive editing is the norm, and posts themselves don't really take up that much space on a site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually had a similar issue, and this is actually because the `publish_post` hook can run more than once, which calls your function each and every time. The best way I found to avoid this was to add a meta field as a flag to each post.

```
add_action( 'publish_post', 'post_type_counter0', 10, 1 );
function post_type_counter0( $ID ){
    $key = '_post_counted';

    if( ! filter_var( get_post_meta( $ID, $key, true ), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN ) ){
        $number0 = get_option( 'wp_count_po0' );

        if( update_option( 'wp_count_po0', ++$number0 ) )
            update_post_meta( $ID, $key, true );
    }
}
```

This function still gets hooked to the [`publish_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post) hook, and passes along the `$ID` of the post.

This lets you check to see if the meta field `_post_counted` returns a truthy value. If it doesn't (returns an empty string because it doesn't exist), then it gets the total, updates the option (the `++` coming before the variable is the [Pre-Increment operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php), so it turns `7` to `8` before storing it). If the option was updated, then it adds the `_post_counted` meta field to the post - meaning if the `publish_post` hook ever runs again on that post, it will just skip over that block, resulting in it not changing.

This has the added benefit of not affecting the total post count when you draft a post to make changes and re-publish it later, or schedule it for posting. The `save_post` hook is more notorious for running multiple times, but the `publish_post` hook absolutely can depending on what your entire WP Environment looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead:

```
$count_posts = wp_count_posts( 'jobs' )->publish;
```

Comment: This will only pull published posts count and whenever I delete a post the number will go down. I want to keep track of posts I will be posting on my blog and always get that number increases and never go down. I will be deleting posts regularly and I dont want that number to go down that is why I am saving the value in an option